# Can a link in a node setup be temporarily disabled?

Tags: node-editor

To debug a messy material node setup in Cycles, I want to remove one link between certain nodes, then restore it when I'm done putzing around.  Being absent-minded, I don't trust myself to remember.

Is there some easy way to turn off a link temporarily, making it as if it weren't there,  without actually deleting it?

Whatever trick there is to do this, it should be visually obvious, so I can see that the link is disabled.

I'm using Cycles for materials right now, but I assume what I'm trying to do could apply to anything using a nodes editor.

Comment: You can mute nodes by pressing M. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that!  Useful, definitely.  Still want to know about muting one link, though.

Comment: I don't think there's an operator to mute a link, but links can be muted, so creating an operator could be possible. In python one would just set ```link.is_muted = True```.

Answer (score 1):

press m to mute (disable) the node